# viewDidUnload versus viewDidDisappear

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

I don't understand when I should implement something in `viewDidUnload` versus `viewDidDisappear`. What's the difference between the two?

For instance, I'd like to send an `NSNotification` when the view controller is removed from the view hierarchy. Between these two methods, does it matter where I post that notification from?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Comment: Why was this voted down? Was the question too vague?

Comment: is the documentation not thorough enough to explain the difference between those two methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is with reference to apple's documentation:-

viewDidUnload:-

When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from memory. This method is called after the view controller’s view has been released and is your chance to perform any final cleanup. If your view controller stores separate references to the view or its subviews, you should use this method to release those references. You can also use this method to remove references to any objects that you created to support the view but that are no longer needed now that the view is gone.

viewDidDisappear:-

Notifies the view controller that its view was removed from a view hierarchy that is everytime view dissapears or move to other view.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidDisappear` is called every time when the view is disappears or you go to other view and `viewDidUnload` is called when the controller’s view is released from memory. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.) [see the reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621383-viewdidunload).

Comment: Thanks, now I realize that viewDidUnload is called when the viewController itself is finally destroyed, but viewDidDisappear is called when you transition to a different view, perhaps further down the view hierarchy. So for instance, if we have view controllers A --> B --> C, and I want to know when B gets destroyed and control returns to A, then I should use viewDidUnload. That's b/c even when B goes to C, viewDidDisappear fires also.

Comment: This is incorrect. `viewDidUnload` is **only** called when the view is released due to a low memory condition. If it's released for other reasons, you'll get no `viewDidUnload` event.